# Type error when using react query useMutation

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-query

I'm using React Query with TypeScript and attempting to make an API call using axios within a useMutation hook. However, I'm encountering a type error and I'm not sure how to resolve it.

```
export const useCreatePoolForm = () => {
   const { submit, register, errors, watch } = useForm(createPoolSchema)

   const { mutate } = useMutation({
      mutationFn: data => {
         return axios.post('/api/pool', data)
      },
      onSuccess: () => {
         toast.success('Pool created')
      },
   })

   const createPool = submit(pool => {
      const answersToArray = pool.answers.split(',').map(answer => answer.trim())

      mutate({
         ...pool,
         answers: answersToArray,
      })
   })

   return {
      createPool,
      register,
      errors,
      watch,
   }
}
```

The error I'm seeing is:

> Argument of type '{ answers: string[]; question: string; expiresAt:
> Date; isPublic: boolean; }' is not assignable to parameter of type
> 'void'.ts(2345)

I am using react hook form and this little wrapper i have for it:

```
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod'
import { useForm as useHookForm } from 'react-hook-form'
import { type z } from 'zod'

export const useForm = <TSchema extends z.ZodSchema>(schema: TSchema) => {
   const {
      register,
      handleSubmit: submit,
      control,
      watch,
      setValue,
      getValues,
      reset,
      formState: { errors },
      clearErrors,
   } = useHookForm<z.infer<typeof schema>>({ resolver: zodResolver(schema) })
   return {
      register,
      submit,
      control,
      watch,
      setValue,
      getValues,
      reset,
      errors,
      clearErrors,
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If someone has encountered the same error here, you should specify the data type explicitly as it is not inferred by default.

```
const { mutate } = useMutation({
   mutationFn: (data: /* specify your type here */) => axios.post('/api/pool', data),
   onSuccess: () => {
      toast.success('Pool created')
   },
})
```

Comment: nit pick: it is inferred, but it is inferred _from_ the `mutationFn`. If you don't type your `mutationFn`, there is nothing to infer from :)